# How to get value of array by using the key from a string

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with some keys and I want to get the array values according to the array keys where the keys are in a string.

Example:

```
$arr = array(
        "COV" => "Comilla Victorians",
        "RK"  => "Rajshaji Kings"
    );

$str = "COV-RK";
```

Now I want to show `Comilla Victorians VS Rajshaji Kings`.

I can do it using some custom looping, But I need some smart coding here and looks your attention. I think there are some ways to make it with array functions that I don't know.

Comment: what you have tried so for? post here

Comment: "I need some smart coding". `echo $arr['COV'] . " VS ".$arr['RK'];`.

Comment: I do with `foreach` loop and some `explode()`, But I want to learn it with array functions. I want to learn... I did't try anything with array functions.

Comment: https://eval.in/661373

Comment: @Al.G., you make an easy terms, here this is just a demo not entire coding, I have the array with 7 teams and the `$str` 50 combinations.

Comment: @Anant, As I said, I did this with these, but I need with array functions.

Comment: @Mysterious  what do you mean by array function?

Comment: `array_combine()`, `array_map()` and etc..., Is there any way to do this with the help of these functions??

Comment: @Mysterious  you have to show your string full (at-least) and based on that expected outcome (more than this one). Otherwise no one understand what you want exactly?

Comment: Finally someone brought a little common sense. Thank you @Anant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
echo implode(' VS ', array_map(function($v) use ($arr) { return $arr[$v]; }, explode('-', $str)));
```

So explode the string, map the resulting array, returning the value of the matching key in `$arr`, then just implode it.

Comment: i din't tested but seems much more accurate. But don't  post answer if people shown no-effort. +1 meanwhile

Comment: Sir, this is awesome, But can you please explain a bit more, I need to learn this things.

Comment: @Mysterious you *only* need to read the docs in php.net. I.e., google "php implode" and if you understand english you should be satisfied.

Comment: The last sentence sums up what's happening, it's pretty straight forward. You can always [read](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) [the](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: @Al.G., Everything's are not in the doc's in understandable way, So some experts can explain it easier for us.

Comment: Well, I find the php language pretty clearly documented compared to other languages (perhaps because php itself is simpler).

Comment: I know I have to learn this kind of silly things and no need to ask for help in stack. I am so so sorry for the silly question. You all are good, just pray for me also.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:-

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    "COV" => "Comilla Victorians",
    "RK"  => "Rajshaji Kings"
);

$str = "COV-RK";

$values = explode("-", $str); // explode string to get keys actually

echo $arr[$values[0]] . " VS " . $arr[$values[1]]; // print desired output
```

Comment: nope. just read some comments and you will know. BTW i didn't down-voted you

Comment: I already do it with the help of explode and foreach, I need to learn array functions for this.

Comment: Yep, I have read the comments, but they were posted after my answer. And, of course, if you don't want people to use the most obvious way (explode) you have to say it in the question, not later.